# not able to delete file in server from client side?

Tags: java, file, jsp, servlets

i am able to get  file names of directory but i am not able delete them

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" import="java.util.* ,java.text.* , java.io.*,java.io.File" errorPage="" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%

    String files; 
    boolean issuccess=true;
    //out.println("hi ");
    String strDirectoy3=config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    //File file = new File("D:\\Test\\hireminibusandcoach.co.uk\\ROOT\\administrator");   FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("c:/a.txt");

    try{

         File file = new File(strDirectoy3); 
        File[] listOfFiles = file.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) 
    {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
        {
            files = listOfFiles[i].getName();

            out.println(listOfFiles[i].toString());
                issuccess=new File(files).delete();


        }
    }

    out.println(" /n Deletion  "+issuccess);
    }catch(Exception e){

        out.println(e);
    }

    %>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you define `not able` ? Any exception ? Error ? Stacktrace ?

Comment: Does your user running web server have rights to delete these files? What parent directory returns for canWrite() method?

Comment: Pls share Exception traces

Comment: hey share the console and db connection and where db connection in your program.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, JSP is not a good place to do things like this. And then Second thing is you are using **JDK7**. It's good to switch to `NIO.2 API` it throws exceptions in the case of failure in old File API does not. So, you should try this to like `NIO.2 API` following as:

```
try 
{
    Path path = file.toPath(); 
    Files.delete(path);
}
catch (NoSuchFileException x) 
{
    System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
}
catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x)  
{
    System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
}
catch (IOException x)  
{
    // File permission problems are caught here.
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

Comment: BTW: I guess that this is lack of permissions problem.

Comment: yes its permission problem it sorted out thanks for your reply

Comment: hey @user3329098, how did you say this answer for that query.

Comment: @jmail: by switching to NIO.2 the exception is thrown, so you will get real problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that user running web server has rights to delete these files. What parent directory returns for canWrite() method?